# emberjs append works but raises Assertion Failed error

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to ember I am trying to append a template to another and it seems to work but it raises an error, can you please explain why?

The error:

```
Assertion failed: You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead
```

This is the code in **app.js**

```
App.NewStickie = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function(evt){
    var stickie = Ember.View.create({
        templateName: 'stickie',
        content: 'write your notes here'
    });
    stickie.appendTo('#stickies');
  }
});
```

These are the contents of **index.html**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view App.NewStickie}}
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
        New
      </button>
    {{/view}}
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <div id="stickies">
      {{#each item in model}}
        <div class="stickie" contenteditable="true">
          {{#view App.DeleteStickie}}
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          {{/view}}
          <div contenteditable="true">
            {{item.content}}
          </div>
        </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="stickie">
    <div class="stickie">
      {{#view App.DeleteStickie}}
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
      {{/view}}
      <div contenteditable="true">
        {{view.content}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each view in ember have a template, for example:

**foo_view.js**

```
App.FooView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'foo'
})
```

**foo template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">   
  <div id=myFooView>Foo</div>
</script>
```

You are trying to insert a view inside of other in that way:

```
App.BarView.create().appendTo('#myFooView')
```

This isn't allowed. You can use the {{view}} handlebars helper to render a view inside other like that:

**foo template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">   
  <div id=myFooView>
    Foo
    {{view App.BarView}}
  </div>
</script>
```

But I think that you want this working dynamically. So you can use the [ContainerView](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html), like described by the error message:

```
App.StickiesView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
  click: function() {
    var stickie = Ember.View.create({
        templateName: 'stickie',
        content: 'write your notes here'
    });
    this.pushObject(stickie);
  }
})
```

I see in your code a lot of views with the click event, ember encourage you to use [actions](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/), this give more flexibility, error/loading handling etc. I think is a good idea to use it.

I hope it helps

Comment: When I change the code to ContainerView the button that calls NewStickie disappears no errors but something is messing with my view.Any idea what that might be? I can post the code from index.html if it's necessary.Thank you!

Comment: index.html could help, please post it

Comment: Is there some reason of why you are using the view click event instead of `{{action "someAction"}}`. Ember encourage the use of actions.

Comment: thanks I have made several changes now I'l mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read [this guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/manually-managing-view-hierarchy/) that explains that `ContainerView` is. Also, I don't think it's necessary to create another `View` to append a template to another template.