# What is the proper way to append view/component to existing view

Tags: ember.js

I have been trying to add a component within a view, I could do it but I am getting some warning message as well like "DEPRECATION: Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported".  There is a related post here : [emberjs append works but raises Assertion Failed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495829/emberjs-append-works-but-raises-assertion-failed-error) but not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my jsbin link : http://jsbin.com/tuwanava/1/

Your help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's working with sticky.pushObject(App.ConfirmDeleteComponent.create()); why not use that?

Comment: It works but then I get this warning message : "DEPRECATION: Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported."

Comment: weird. I'm not getting that deprecation error

Comment: Oh sorry you were right, it is working..sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
sticky.pushObject(App.ConfirmDeleteComponent.create());
```