# Dynamic views based on content in an Ember.js CMS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm very new to both Ember and web development. Let's say that I'm building a site that displays news articles. I'd like some interaction with Wikipedia links in each article so that when you click on them, a little box will pop up in place with the summary (like the Instapaper app). I'd also like some interaction within the box, expanding and collapsing the summary, etc. What is the most Ember-like way to do this?

I think that with jQuery it would be trivial to add a click handler to the links to add the box to the DOM, but I'd really like the box to be an Ember view. I thought I might have been able to  create a view dynamically and append it to a DOM element but it seems that it [isn't allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495829/emberjs-append-works-but-raises-assertion-failed-error), and you can only append to ContainerViews.

How should I approach this?

## Update on what I've tried

Essentially, I have this as a template for each article so there are paragraphs and a container on the right of each paragraph for the boxes:

```
{{#each paragraph}}
    <div class='paragraph-container'>
        <p {{bind-attr id=paragraph_id}}>{{html_text}}</p>
        <div class='paragraph-reference-container' {{bind-attr id=paragraph_reference_id}}></div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

And an associated view. `paragraph_reference_id` and `paragraph_id` are computed properties so I can set the IDs properly here. I also have a ReferenceView for the boxes, which is uninteresting since it's just placeholder content and code at the moment. I was racking my brain trying to figure this out, and ended up trying something like this to append the view [as was in the documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/defining-a-view/):

```
App.ArticleView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'article',
    classNames: ['articles'],
    didInsertElement: function () {
        var container = this.container;
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function () {
            var em = this;
            em.$('.paragraph-container').each(function () {
                var referenceContainerID = $('.paragraph-reference-container', this).first().prop('id');
                em.$('a.wikipedia-link', this).click(function () {
                    var referenceView = container.lookup('view:reference');
                    referenceView.appendTo('#' + referenceContainerID);
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

But I got the "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead." error. Apparently this is no longer supported as mentioned above. I don't really know what the "Ember" way is to do this and still use views (which I'd really like to do) instead of plain HTML and jQuery.

Comment: You should post what have you tried so far. This question is too broad to answer "correctly".

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk I've updated my question. Hope that helps.